# Fix Non-Continuous Grease Pencil Strokes?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I'm having a problem with grease pencil strokes in Blender.

[image]

Zoomed out view:

[image]

As you can see, the strokes are not smooth flowing lines, but are separate line segments assembled in the shape of the line. As I'm trying to use Blender's grease pencil for 2D animation as others have done in the past, this will not work very well. Does anyone know of a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post all relevant information to your question, including the images, directly and not in another site. If the links change the question will make no more sense and will not be useful.

Comment: That's true. The only reason I didn't post the images directly is because I didn't know I had permission to post them. I thought that you had to have a certain reputation score in order to do that.

Comment: The problem goes away when I convert to a bezier curve, so I guess that works.